# how to invisible field based on the dropdown selection field in ODOO

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

[error msg after added invisible attr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BkHBv.png)[Added image here depending upon group bellow notepad tree view fields can be change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyNy3.png)
Hi friends I am beginner to ODOO or OpenERP, I have scenario in that based on selection field notepad tree view can be changed so I have given my code sample-
should I add invisible then where should I add?
XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<openerp>
<data>
    <record id="feeder_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
                <field name="name">feeder.data.tree</field>
                <field name="model">feeder.data</field>
                <field name="arch" type="xml">
                    <tree string="Feeder">
                            <field name="date_of1"/>
                <!--<field name="folio_num1"/>
                            <field name="max_mw"/>-->
                            <field name="company_id1"/>

                    </tree>
                </field>
        </record>
    <record id="feeder_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">feeder.data.form</field>
        <field name="model">feeder.data</field>

        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Feeder">
                <group>
                <!--<field name="company_id1"/>-->
                <field name="date_of1"/>
                <field name="group_name" on_change="get_feeder_catg(group_name)"/>
                <!--<field name="folio_num1"/>--></group>
                <field name="combine2">
                    <form string="Enter">
                    <group>
                        <!--<field name="company_id1"/>
                        <field name="Hours"/>
                        <field name="time_read"/>-->
                        <field name="Hours"/>
                        <field name="mega_wat"/>
                        <field name="current"/>
                        <field name="wt"/>
                        <field name="ot"/>
                        <field name="tp"/>
                        <!--<field name="Max"/>-->
                    </group>
                    </form>
                    <tree limit='24' string="BoM" editable="bottom">
                        <!--<field name="company_id1"/>
                        <field name="Hours"/>
                        <field name="time_read"/>-->
                        <field name="Hours"/>
                        <field name="mega_wat"/>
                        <field name="current"/>
                        <field name="wt"/>
                        <field name="ot" attrs="{'invisible':                                                  [('group_name', '=','Feeder')]}"/>
                        <field name="tp" attrs="{'invisible':[('group_name', '=','Feeder')]}"/>
                        <!--<field name="Max"/>-->
                    </tree>

                </field>
            <!--<group><field name="max_mw"/></group>-->

            </form>     


        </field>

    </record>
    <record id="feeder_data_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Feeder Data</field>
        <!--<field name="type">ir.actions.act_window</field>-->
        <field name="res_model">feeder.data</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>  


        <field name="view_mode">tree,form</field>  

        <field name="help" type="html">
                <p class="oe_view_nocontent_create">Click to create a               new AssetConfigs</p>
        </field>    
    <!--<record model="ir.actions.act_window.view"      id="action_feeder_tree_view">
                <field name="sequence" eval="1"/>
                <field name="view_mode">tree</field>
                <field name="view_id" ref="feeder_tree_view"/>
                <field name="act_window_id" ref="feeder_data_action"/>
        </record>-->
        </record>[error msg][2]
```

class feeder_data(osv.Model):

```
_name = "feeder.data"
_rec_name= "company_id1"

_columns = {
    'company_id1': fields.many2one('res.company', 'Substation', required=True),
    'date_of1':fields.datetime('Date',),
    'group_name':fields.many2one('feeder.catg','Please Select Group'),



    'combine2':fields.one2many('data.value','combine','Details'),

       }

def get_feeder_catg(self, cr, uid, ids, group_name,context=None):
    val = {}
    res = []
    res2 = []
    res3 = []
    if group_name:
        for asset in self.pool.get('feeder.catg').browse(cr,uid,group_name,context=context):
            for ass in asset.combine_table:
                val = {
                    'Hours' : ass.feeder.folio_num,
                    'company_id1': ass.company_id1.name,
                    #'time_read':date.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

                    }

                res.append(val)
                logging.info("VAL=%d",val)
                logging.info("RES=%d",res)

        val.update({'combine2':res,})
    return {'value': val}

def _default_company(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    user = self.pool.get('res.users').browse(cr, uid, uid, context=context)
        if user.company_id:
            return user.company_id.id
        return self.pool.get('res.company').search(cr, uid, [('parent_id', '=', False)])[0]

_defaults = {
    'date_of1': datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d'),
    'company_id1': _default_company,
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an related field for it and add that related field in attrs.

```
 _name = 'feeder.data'
 _columns= {'group_name_related' :fields.related('group_name','field_name', type = 'char', relation='target_table_name', string='Name')}


  <tree>
    <field name='name' attrs="{'invisible' : [('group_name_related','=','GroupName')]}">
  </tree>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response,but group name field is in another field I have edited my post and added xml code and error msg screenshot.

Comment: sir but my field group_name is already many2one relation.   'group_name':fields.many2one('feeder.catg','Please Select Group'),
 so how to change this to related

Comment: You have to create new related field that's what meant. Then you will have two group field on is m2o and related field, use related field value in attrs as condition for invisible

Comment: Sir I am getting syntax error in that line, please see                       _columns = {
  'company_id1': fields.many2one('res.company', 'Substation', required=True),
  'date_of1':fields.datetime('Date',),
  'group_name':fields.many2one('feeder.catg','Please Select Group'),
  'group_name_related' :fields.related('group_name','field_name', type = 'char', relation='data.value', string='Name')
  
  
  'combine2':fields.one2many('data.value','combine','Details'),
  
           }

Comment: Please change second attribute 'field_name' in related field  to a field in feeder.categ table which you want to use in invisible condition. Sorry for my language..

Comment: Sir, actually I am getting this error:                                                                                        Error: Error: Unknown field group_name_related in domain [["group_name_related","=","Transformer"]]

Comment: I have added this line target object name and type is correct?                                             'group_name_related' :fields.related('group_name','Transformer', type = 'char', relation='data.value', string='Name'),

Comment: Try this: 
Add this line after grorp_name field in feeder.data model
 'group_name_related' :fields.related('group_name','name', type = 'char', relation='feeder.catg', string='Name'),

Comment: Sir, I have tried your suggetion still getting same error.                                                     'group_name_related' :fields.related('group_name','name12', type = 'char', relation='feeder.catg', string='Name'),

Comment: Sir I have used the follwing line instead of earlier so getting __init__ argument passed  2 (given2) error please fix it.                                                                         'name12':fields.selection(string='Nickname',store=True,related='group_name.name12'),

Comment: Try once again earlier line and add below line in your xml file

<tree>
<field name = 'group_name_related' />
    <field name='name' attrs="{'invisible' : [('group_name_related','=','GroupName')]}"/>
  </tree>

Comment: Sir, I have added  <field name = 'group_name_related' />  field in <tree> but it is giving error that group_name_related not found.

Comment: Try this:''group_name_related':fields.char(string='Related group name', related='group_name.name'). Use group_name.name instead of group_name.name12

Comment: name12 we are used for selection field in feeder.catg so I am using that one sir,If I change to name giving error.